# While trying to fetch data from api Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

I have tried implementing this code to fetch data from API.

This is my product.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from '../common/product';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  
 public baseURL ='http://localhost:8080/getBooks'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  users(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }
 
}
```

This is my homecompoent.ts

```
export class HomeComponent {
  public sort: string;
  public books: any ;
  constructor(private bookData:ProductService) 
  { 
    this.bookData.books().subscribe((data) => {
      this.books = data;
  });
  }
```

Please Please tell me the about the error why I'm getting this subscribe error.

Comment: What kind of error do you have ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `book()` method doesn't return an `Observable` but a `void` type.

Comment: I got the mistake i did...In product i described users() and in ts I'm using books(). Thanks it was silly mistake from my end.. Sorry.